# iPhone facebook application user is getting an error I can't see, why?

Tags: iphone, facebook

One of our users are having problems accessing our application on the iPhone and I can't reproduce it.  she is seeing:

> Either this application has not configured its Mobile Web URL or the URL could not be verified as owned by the application. Unable to redirect.

If I go to that link on own iPhone it shows just fine. If I go to the application via http://m.facebook.com it also doesn't have any trouble displaying.

I do not have a mobile tab configured as we don't have a mobile version of the application, however since it seem to be working fine on my end (it show's the full version), I'd like to know why the user is seeing this error and I'm not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting the same problem reported from some of my users, links are posted through dlvr.it. It has only started over the last week, but seems to be a repeat of the problem reported back in March. See http://support.dlvr.it/entries/21177033-facebook-error-either-this-application-has-not-configured-its-mobile-web-url

Those having the problem have recently upgraded their Facebook app, so I assume it's a Facebook problem.

Answer (score 0):

i saw exact same error. i followed instruction on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/,  when i tapped the link  https://m.facebook.com/apps/MY_APPNAMESPACE in facebook iphone app, it started safari with that link, but safari can not redirect me to my iphone app.

in dev facebook app setting page, i only enabled web site and native iphone app two options, mobile web is not enabled. I doubt if it could be cause

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. This is my set up and how I solved it:

I have a native iOS app that integrates with facebook. It uses SSO. On my apps page on developers.facebook.com, I had the "Native iOS App" section filled out, so the iOS Facebook app would correctly launch my app when a user tapped on links that were set to https://m.facebook.com/apps/MY_APP_NAMESPACE

I got the error in question if I clicked on those same links via the normal Facebook web site on a desktop.

I solved the problem by adding my app's website to the "Mobile Web URL" field. i.e. Go to the basic settings page for your app on developers.facebook.com. Under "Select how your app integrates with facebook," enable "Mobile Web" in addition to "Native iOS App." Then fill out the "Mobile Web URL" field.